# How to get a $_FILES array from a distant image URL?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have just spent a long time looking for a solution and apart from a not so good 2012 answer , I have unfortunately not found anything conclusive.

I am currently working with CakePHP 3.x and the [cakephp-upload](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload) plugin and everything is running smoothly! However, the cakephp-upload pluging doesn't allow me to upload remote documents. I'd like to avoid developing a new algorithm just for that.

The plugin only accepts a `$_FILE` array as input. I was wondering if it was possible, from a remote URL, to simulate a classic file `$_POST` sending? If this is not possible, how would you tackle the problem?

Comment: What do you mean `... upload remote documents`? The `$_FILES` global array will be populated if your upload form is set up correctly. This should allow you to upload anything you wish.

Comment: Well I meant documents from another website. In my case, I just want to download a Youtube thumbnail from the http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/%ID%/hqdefault.jpg URL. I cloud just use `the file_get_contents` / `file_put_contents` method but I’ll have to write again all the verification and rules that cakephp-upload already do. That’s fine but I wanted to check with you guys if another method was possible.

Comment: So you want to fetch a resource from another site? That wouldn't be an upload then. That'd be a download. You can look into `CURL` or as you suggested, `file_get_contents`. Perhaps if you explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish, we'd be able to suggest an approach. Please edit your question and post any updated in there, as opposed to adding comments here. Thx!